# jQuery show/hide a specific div with a checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

OK, I have an issue with some code and I'm really not sure how to code the outcome that I want to achieve.

I'm working on a site using Laravel 5.2 and I'm having an issue with hiding and showing specific divs based on the status of a checkbox. These are in a @foreach loop but I'm fairly sure that the laravel/@foreach isn't the issue, it's my lack of jQuery experience.

So here's some code.

```
 @foreach ($event->extras()->get() as $extra)
    <p>{{ $extra->name }}</p>
    <p>{{ $extra->cost }}</p>
    <p><input type="checkbox" name="extra-checkbox" id="extra-checkbox" value=""></p>
    <div id="extra-info">
         @if ($extra->infoRequired == "1")
             <input type="text" name="extra-info-text" class="form-control">
         @endif
    </div>
@endforeach
```

The issue I'm having is that the $extra variable ID's ($extra->id) in the loop could be very different so a for-loop in the javascript is out. Each checkbox needs to show/hide only the specific "extra-info" div it is associated with.

How do I modify the following code to make it work for each individual $extra independently? I've considered putting the $extra->id into the class or div id but I can't figure out how to then implement it in the javascript.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#extra-checkbox').change(function() {
        if(this.checked)
            $('#extra-info').fadeIn('fast');
        else
            $('#extra-info').fadeOut('fast');
```

**Edit**
I've added an id to the html as it's omission was my copying error. The issue I need to get my head around is that there will be multiple checkboxes (they're actually in a table, not `<p>`, but I was trying to make the code readable). Each checkbox is associated with an $extra and each $extra has it's own div that needs to be shown when the checkbox is checked.

Comment: What's the output of the HTML coming in?

Comment: Get the output HTML, and create a JsFiddle, that will be more convenient

Comment: You don't have a checkbox with extra-checkbox id. Your jQuery will never fire

Comment: A very simple way would be this one: wrap the whole foreach body in its own `div` element and make `extra-info` a class instead of an id. Then the checkbox handler can use this jquery expression to get the specific element: `$(this).parent().children().filter('.extra-info')`

Comment: It looks like in trying to simplify my code to get some help in figuring out how to do this dynamically I screwed up the copying of my code, sorry! There is an ID in the checkbox <input>. The main problem is that I have a varying number of checkboxes each with unpredictable ID numbers.

Comment: @bioinforach Check my answer, if that helps in without having the ID to be repetitive and no JS required.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few mistakes in your code.

1. You **cannot** duplicate `id` values. You are doing it. Change it class.
2. Don't put `<input />` inside `<p>`, instead, wrap it inside `<label>`.
3. Using `$('#extra-checkbox')` doesn't work, because it is `name` not `id`. Use `$('[name="extra-checkbox"]')`.
4. This can be done using CSS itself. See below.

See the working example here:

```css
input[name="extra-checkbox"] + input[name="extra-info-text"] {display: none;}
input[name="extra-checkbox"]:checked + input[name="extra-info-text"] {display: inline;}
```

```html
<div class="entry">
  <p>Name 1</p>
  <p>Cost 1</p>
  <div class="form-stuff">
    <input type="checkbox" name="extra-checkbox" value="">
    <input type="text" name="extra-info-text" class="form-control">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="entry">
  <p>Name 2</p>
  <p>Cost 2</p>
  <div class="form-stuff">
    <input type="checkbox" name="extra-checkbox" value="">
    <input type="text" name="extra-info-text" class="form-control">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="entry">
  <p>Name 3</p>
  <p>Cost 3</p>
  <div class="form-stuff">
    <input type="checkbox" name="extra-checkbox" value="">
    <input type="text" name="extra-info-text" class="form-control">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="entry">
  <p>Name 4</p>
  <p>Cost 4</p>
  <div class="form-stuff">
    <input type="checkbox" name="extra-checkbox" value="">
    <input type="text" name="extra-info-text" class="form-control">
  </div>
</div>
```

You don't need jQuery or JavaScript for this.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have input with id extra-checkbox, try this:

```
$('input[name="extra-checkbox"]').change(function() {
    if(this.checked) {
        $('#extra-info').fadeIn('fast');
    } else {
        $('#extra-info').fadeOut('fast');
    }
});
```

or use a class since you should not have more then one element with same id.

Comment: Man, see the comment for the answer below. `:/`

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the same id to multiple divs, this is bad. You need to add a unique id or a unique data attribute to every element and reference it in you change event.

Also:

```
$('#extra-checkbox')
```

should be this:

```
$('*[name="extra-checkbox"]')
```

This should work:

```
@foreach ($event->extras()->get() as $extra)
        <p>{{ $extra->name }}</p>
        <p>{{ $extra->cost }}</p>
        <p><input type="checkbox" name="extra-checkbox" value="{{ $extra->name }}"></p>
        <div class="extra-info" data-name="{{ $extra->name }}">
             @if ($extra->infoRequired == "1")
                 <input type="text" name="extra-info-text" class="form-control">
             @endif
        </div>
@endforeach
```

then

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('*[name="extra-checkbox"]').change(function() {
        if($(this).prop('checked'))
            $('.extra-info[data-name="'+$(this).data('name')+'"]').fadeIn('fast');
        else
            $('.extra-info[data-name="'+$(this).data('name')+'"]').fadeOut('fast');
```

Comment: Hi, this is *exactly* what I was thinking, I just don't know how to do it...hence the post. Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

Use pusedo selctors to get if checkbox is checked or not

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#extra-checkbox').change(function() {
        if($(this).is(":checked"){  //Return true/false 
            $('#extra-info').fadeIn('fast');
         }
        else{
            $('#extra-info').fadeOut('fast'); 
    }
})
```

**EDIT AFTER COMMENTS**

You can use which is prefix selector, which mean if any `id` which start with extra_checkbox will respond to this snippet.

```
$('div[id^="extra-checkbox"]')
```

For more information visit [HERE](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

NOTE: id need to be unique as per W3C standard

Comment: I agree with the unique ID. I can create one with id="extra-checkbox-{{$extra->id}}" but then how do I get the javascript to respond to this when the $extra->id can't be predicted?

Comment: Thank you!! It's exactly what I was after. Sometimes it's difficult to search for something you know *should* exist but you don't know what it's called or how to find it.

Comment: @bioinforach jCubic actually gave the same solution an hour before this solution was posted, and also that solution is efficient than this, why did you reply to this and didn't look at the other one?

Comment: @user2181397 I believe you know about StackOverflow, having so much rep, the OP cannot vote you up!